# Convert a "table1"-table to pdf-friendly format

Tags: r, html-table, r-markdown

I have a table with descriptive statistics I generated using the `table1` package (I used it since it can produce descriptive statistics for both categorical and continuous variables). The issue I'm having is that `table1` only produce tables in HTML-format. I'd like to transform my `table1`-table to a `kable`-table (or equivalent) so I knit my markdown to a pdf-file.

I tried the following code

```
library(table1)
library(kable)

tb <- table1(reformulate(colnames(df)), data=df, output = "latex")
kable(tb, caption = "Descriptive statistics")
```

But this produces an empty table looking like this:

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this?